# if i click in body nothing change but if i clicked in image itself it changed why?

Tags: javascript, dom

if i click in body nothing change but if i clicked in image itself it changed why?

```js
let element = document.querySelector("img");
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  element.src = "images/2.jpg";
})
```

```html
<img src="x">
```

Comment: Bind the listener directly to the `document`  object. The body probably has not enough content to cover the entire window.

Comment: I agree with @Ram  re the body , try making the HTML and body take up all the space with css- HTML, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block}; which should allow the click to register

Answer (score 0):

try to give the body a color using CSS.
body by default takes the content height and 100% of the width.
if you want to make the event happen when clicking on the screen you should apply the event on the HTML tag or give the body 100% width and height.

```css
    body {
      width :100%; 
      height: 100%;
    }
```